# I need to Pop an item off of a Stack into a variable and Push the original Variable onto another Array

Tags: javascript, function, stack, push, javascript-objects

I have 2 Arrays and a Variable. I am able to push an item into a variable, and then on a second click, add it to an Array. However, i have another button that moves an item from that Array, back into the Variable and move the variable into another Array. 
My code works on the first section, however my function does now load for the second, any help please?

It is this section that does not seem to work

```
<INPUT type=button value="Back" onClick='txtPop.value = popBackStack();showStack(theList);pushForStack(curUrl);
showStack2(theList2);'>
```

The whole code is below:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Stacking up!</TITLE>
<SCRIPT>

var backStack = new Array(); 
var forStack = new Array();
var curUrl = document.getElementById("txtPop");

function pushStack(newVal) {
backStack.push(curUrl);
curUrl = newVal;
}

function pushForStack(newVal) {
CurUrl = newVal;
forstack.push(curUrl);
}

function popBackStack() {
var popVal = backStack.pop();  
if (popVal == undefined)
  return "Nothing left!";
else
return popVal
}

function popForStack() {
var popVal = forStack.pop();
if (popVal == undefined)
  return "Enter a new URL";
else
return popVal;
}

function showStack(theSelect){
theSelect.options.length = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < backStack.length; i++){
  var theOption = new Option(backStack[i]);
  theSelect.options[theSelect.options.length] = theOption;
}
}

function showStack2(theSelect){
theSelect.options.length = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < forStack.length; i++){
  var theOption = new Option(forStack[i]);
  theSelect.options[theSelect.options.length] = theOption;
}
}
 </SCRIPT>


</HEAD>
<BODY>
<FORM>
<table width="104%" height="364" border="5" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3">
<tr>
<th width="30%" height="78" scope="col"><p>
<INPUT type=button value="Back" onClick='txtPop.value =     popBackStack();showStack(theList);pushForStack(curUrl);
showStack2(theList2);'></p></th>
<th width="46%" scope="col"><p>
<center>
<INPUT type=text name=txtPush>
<INPUT type=button value="Push"   onClick='pushStack(txtPush.value);txtPush.value="";txtPop.value = curUrl;   showStack(theList);'>
</center>
</p></th>
<th width="24%" scope="col"><p><INPUT type=button value="Forward" onClick="txtPop.value      = popBackStack();showStack2(theList2);"></p></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><p><center>
<SELECT name="theList" size=12>
</SELECT>
</center></p></td>
<td><p><center><INPUT type=textki name=txtPop size=25></center></p></td>
<td><center>
<SELECT name="theList2" size=12>
</SELECT>
</center></td>
</tr>
</table>
</FORM>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try turning the curUrl into a new array and pop from backStack onto curUrl and then pop curUrl onto forStack.

```
curUrl = new Array ()
```